# If $||f||_{L^p}<\infty $ for all $p\geq 1$, then $||f||_{L^{\infty}}<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space with positive measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(X) = 1$. Let $f$ be an integrable function. I have been working on a proof for $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}||f||_{L^p} = ||f||_{L^\infty}$, and  I have it all worked out except one piece:

If $||f||_{L^{p}}<\infty$ for all $p \geq 1$, then $||f||_{L^{\infty}}<\infty$

Here I am using the definition $||f||_{L^{\infty }} = \inf \big\{\lambda:|f|\leq \lambda \;a.e.\big\}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're just proving $\lim_{p\to\infty} \|f\|_{L^p} = \|f\|_{L^\infty}$, you probably wanted to prove "if there is some $M > 0$ such that $\|f\|_{L^p} \leq M < \infty$ for all $p \geq 1$, then $\|f\|_{L^\infty} < \infty$"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true. The $p$-norm of $x \mapsto \log(1/x)$ on $(0,1)$ is $(\Gamma(p+1))^{1/p}<\infty$, but its $\infty$-norm is not finite.

Comment: Interesting, I guess one of the solutions to the proof that $||f||_p \rightarrow ||f||_\infty$ I saw on here made a false assumption. Thanks!